# Particle Physics: Centre-of-mass Frame for Three Particles?

Tags: particle-physics

For a two-two process $1 + 2 \rightarrow 3 + 4$, we define the centre-of mass as the frame where both the initial- and final-state particles are back-to-back, i. e. $\vec{p}_1 = -\vec{p}_2$ and $\vec{p}_3 = -\vec{p}_4$.

Now let's assume that we look at the following two processes:

(i) $\pi^{0}\rightarrow \gamma\gamma$,

(ii) $\mu^{-}\rightarrow e^{-}\bar{\nu}_{e}\nu_{\mu}$.

**Question**:
For (i), the centre-of-mass frame would be the rest frame of the $\pi^{0}$, i. e. the two photons would still come out back-to-back.

But how would this look like for (ii), i. e. how is the centre-of-mass defined there?

Comment: The CM frame means simply that the sum of three-momenta on each side vanishes, i.e. if you have $\vec p_0 \rightarrow \sum_i \vec p_i$. Then it the CM frame you have $\vec p_0 = 0 = \sum_i \vec p_i$, i.e. the sum of outgoing three-momenta sum to zero.

Answer (score 3):

The frame that is useful for these calculations is the *zero-momentum* or *centre-of-momentum* frame. It is the frame of reference in which the vector sum of the bodies' momenta is zero. [To be pedantic, the *centre-of-mass* frame is a special case in which the centre of mass is at the origin of co-ordinates – usually an unnecessary requirement.]

So your rest frame for the muon is itself the centre-of-momentum frame. The three reaction products can come out in various directions, provided that their momenta sum vectorially to zero. In other words the sum of the momentum components in any direction you choose is zero.

**Addendum**: the "various directions" must be such that $(\mathbf p_1 \times \mathbf p_2).\mathbf p_3 =0$, that is the momenta of the three particles need to be coplanar. [Just consider the plane defined by two of them; the third one mustn't point out of this plane as its component normal to the plane could never be balanced if there are only 3 vectors!]